# attribute value added cart checkout and order page

Tags: magento

I am using Magento Version 1.7.0.2

I have added available_color for different product color(newly added attributes) check box in product detail page.using below code

app\design\frontend\default{mytempalte}\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

```
<?php
        $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('available_colors')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        $color = $_product->getAttributeText('available_colors');


        ?>
        <h2>Item Color</h2>
        <?php foreach ($color as $value): ?>
            <label class="span4" style="margin-left:0px;">
            <input class="pro_color_<?php echo $value; ?>" name="<?php echo $value; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" type="checkbox">
            <?php echo $value; ?>                   
            </label>                    
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

customer can able to select the multiple color .After select the product color I need to show multiple color value  in cart and checkout and order page.

how to pass the color value from product detail to other page?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Custom Options feature for this instead of using an attribute.
[Here is a nice screencast about custom options](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HbSH2cPrdo).
You just have to create a custom option with type `checkbox` and use as values you colors. The downside of this is that if you want the options for more products, you will have to manually add the option for all. Or you can search for an extension that allows one custom option for multiple products.
After adding the options, you don't have to do anything. They will be added as options to the cart.

Comment: Custom options are not actual or any other type of product attributes. They do not show in attribute sets.
I have already tried it but I need other option like custom attributes.